# How can I list all unfiled Dropbox Paper documents, ones not in a folder?

Tags: dropbox

Dropbox Paper lets you put documents into folders. A doc cannot belong to more than one folder, but it can be part of no folders. The Dropbox Paper interface indicates a document belongs to no folder by marking it with the word "unfiled".

If I want to see all the Dropbox Paper documents in a folder, I can navigate my way to that folder. But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for unfiled Dropbox Paper documents.

How do I list all the Dropbox Paper documents in my account that are unfiled?

Answer (score 1):

I use this hack

```
items= [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('hp-list-item')); unfiled= items.filter((z) => z.text.match('Unfiled')); items.map((i) => i.style.display = 'none'); unfiled.map((i) => i.style.display = 'flex')
```